# Center login page but not logged in page

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to center a login page:
https://secure.workbooks.com/process/=QzM/Customer_Support_Portal

However since the logged in page is full width there's no need for it to be centered.

How can I approach this?

Thanks,

Sam

Comment: You can try to set a {width:??px} and a {margin : 0 auto} for the #wrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

**CSS**

```
.loginform, .registrationform, .forgotpasswordform, .passwordsetform {
    left: 50%;
    position: relative;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    width: 480px;
}
```

**OR**

```
.loginform, .registrationform, .forgotpasswordform, .passwordsetform {
    width: 480px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

If you like to center the title, add a class:

**CSS**

```
h1.login-title{
text-align:center;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<h1 class="login-title">Customer Support Portal - Login</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

give the width to wrap div & then use the margin: 0 auto to center it.

```
#wrap{
    width: 480px;
    margin: o auto;
}
```

For form change the width & add margin : 0 auto;

```
.emailbox{
    width: 209px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

for footer add text-align property

```
#footer{
    text-align: center;
}
```